# Applying Log Laws vs Solver solution

Tags: solution-verification, logarithms, exponential-function

Trying to solve this:

$$0.2{e}^{\frac{-{x}^{2}}{2}}=0.8{e}^{\frac{-{(x-1)}^{2}}{2}}$$
in a solver gives the first step:
${\ln0.2} - {\frac{{x}^{2}}{2}} = {\ln0.8} - {\frac{{(x-1)}^{2}}{2}}$.

Based on my understanding of log laws, taking the natural log of the equation and taking down the exponent would lead to this:
$-{\frac{{x}^{2}}{2}}{\ln0.2} -  =  -{\frac{{(x-1)}^{2}}{2}}{\ln0.8} $.

Is my answer incorrect and could somebody explain the difference?

Comment: The log of a product is the sum of the logs.

Comment: The correct law is $\ln(ab)=\ln a + \ln b$. It seems you are using $\ln(ab)=\ln a \cdot \ln b$ which is incorrect.

Comment: That clarified it, thank you!